# SharePoint Online List Settings - Catalog no access

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, catalog

I am currently using SharePoint online and trying to configure a publishing site to link to a Catalog list in another site within the collection.

I have enabled Cross Site Publishing Features and need to edit some of the Catalog settings on the List I want to drive the catalog.

In the List settings I have the Catalog option shown but clicking the entry just display a page stating I haven't got access.
[image: SharePoint Catalog Image]

Is this feature available in SharePoint online? I've not been able to find a definitive answer.
[image: SharePoint No Access]

Answer (score 0):

Check your permission within List... Are you having full control within the list as well